# Block Future Automatic Installs of Office 365 and Word Opening On it's Own when it not supposed to be installed

Tags: microsoft-word, installation, microsoft-office, office365, automatic-update

During the past year or two Office 365 has magically reappeared on the computer multiple times. I have uninstalled it; so, there should be no trace. Yet, it Microsoft Word opens itself automatically for no reason every few months. Looking at the list of installed programs see a fresh unauthorized installation of Office 365.

Windows 10 Updates are already disabled and have been for some time. Why does Office 365 reinstall itself every few months? More importantly, How do I block this?.

I did not try to open a document, I did not ask to have Word on my machine. Why does it reinstall itself, and how do we disable it completely.

I have Home edition so there is no "group policy" that I can change on this computer. Hours of internet searching have revealed that there apparently aren't other people on Earth who hate it.

Is there a way to edit the registry to permanently disable Office 365 downloads and installations. I don't even want Windows 10 to be able to check for updates, much less download anything and install it in the background.

Can anyone tell me how to edit the registry (or something) so my computer will function like it's 1995 again?

Comment: I think sometimes Microsoft may do product promotion in a certain way. If you encounter this situation, please make sure that you don’t accept it.

Comment: There is also [Let's finish setting up your device](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/why-am-i-getting-this-quot-let-s-finish-setting-up-your-device/m-p/1751604) which may re-install any of the free versions of Office if they are not present.

Answer (score 1):

I am not denying your experience, but do not know of any such automatic installation.

### Here are instructions for uninstalling Office including any kernel bits.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8  **Look at Option 2** on that page. The text below is from that page but I recommend going to the page which has options depending on the version as well as the browser.

> **Option 2** - Completely uninstall Office with the uninstall support tool
>
> ```
> Click the button below to download and install the Office uninstall support tool.
> ```
>
> **[Button](https://aka.ms/SaRA-officeUninstallFromPC)**
>
> 2. Follow the steps below to download the uninstall support tool according to your browser.
>
> Tip: The tool may take a few minutes to download and install. After
> completing the installation, the Uninstall Office products window will
> open.
>
> Uninstall Office from a PC Office 2019 Office 2016 Office for business
> Microsoft 365 admin More...
>
> The following steps describe how to uninstall Office products on a PC
> (laptop, desktop, or 2-in-1). For Mac, see Uninstall Office for Mac.
>
> Tip: Uninstalling Office only removes the Office applications from
> your computer, it doesn't remove any files, documents, or workbooks
> you created using the apps. Uninstall Office for your installation
> type
>
> The steps to uninstall Office depend on the type of installation you
> have. The most common installation types are Click-to-Run and
> Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI). The other type is an Office
> installation from the Microsoft Store app.
>
> Select the Click-to-Run or MSI or Microsoft Store tab below and follow
> those uninstall steps for your installation type.
>
> Not sure which type of install you have? Expand this section if you're
> not sure which installation type you have Click-to-Run or MSI
> Microsoft Store
>
> If you have a Click-to-Run or an MSI installation, uninstall Office
> using the Control Panel or download the uninstall support tool. Option
> 1 - Uninstall Office from the Control Panel
>
> ```
> Open the Control Panel.
>
> Tip: If you installed the Office apps as part of a suite, such as Office Home and Student or Microsoft 365, search for the suite name.
> ```
>
> For stand-alone apps search by the app name, such as Project or Visio.
>
> ```
> In most cases you can't uninstall an individual app if it's included in your Office suite. The only way to uninstall an individual
> ```
>
> app is if you purchased it as a stand-alone app.
>
> ```
> How you open the Control Panel depends on your version of Windows.
>
> Windows 10
>
>     In the search box on the task bar, type control panel, then select Control Panel.
>
>     Select Programs > Programs and Features, then right-click your Microsoft Office product, and choose Uninstall.
>
> Windows 8.1 or 8
>
>     Right-click the Start button Windows Start button in Windows 8 and Windows 10 (lower-left corner), and choose Control Panel.
>
>     Select Programs and Features, then right-click your Office product, and choose Uninstall.
>
> Windows 7
>
>     Click Start > Control Panel.
>
>     Click Programs > Programs and Features.
>
>     Right-click the Office application you want to remove, and then click Uninstall.
>
> Follow the prompts to complete the uninstall.
>
> Note: If Office isn't listed in the Control Panel you could have a Microsoft Store installation type. Select the Microsoft Store tab
> ```
>
> above and follow those uninstall steps instead.
>
> ```
> To reinstall Office select the version you want to reinstall and follow those steps.
>
> Microsoft 365 | Office 2019 | Office 2016 | Office 2013 | Office 2010 | Office 2007
> ```
>
> Option 2 - Completely uninstall Office with the uninstall support tool
>
> ```
> Click the button below to download and install the Office uninstall support tool.
>
> Follow the steps below to download the uninstall support tool according to your browser.
>
> Tip: The tool may take a few minutes to download and install. After completing the installation, the Uninstall Office products
> ```
>
> window will open.
>
> Instructions for different browsers:
>
> ```
> Edge or Chrome
>
>     In the lower-lower left corner right-click SetupProd_OffScrub.exe > Open.
>     Where to find and open the Support Assitant download file in a Chrome web browser 
>
> Edge (older) or Internet Explorer
>
>     At the bottom of the browser window, select Run to launch the SetupProd_OffScrub.exe.
>     Where to find and open the Support Assitant download file in the Edge or Internet Explorer web browser 
>
> Firefox
>
>     In the pop-up window, select Save Fileand then from the upper-right browser window, select the downloads arrow >
> ```
>
> SetupProd_OffScrub.exe.
> Where to find and open the Support Assitant download file in a Chrome web browser
>
> ```
> Select the version you want to uninstall, and then select Next.
>
> Follow through the remaining screens and when prompted, restart your computer.
>
> After you restart your computer, the uninstall tool automatically re-opens to complete the final step of the uninstall process. Follow
> ```
>
> the remaining prompts.
>
> ```
> If you want to reinstall Office, select the steps for the version you want and follow those steps. Close the uninstall tool.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. SetupProd_OffScrub worked well here- it didn't automatically detect Office 2019 at launch, so we had to selected it from the list of Office versions.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Comment: Microsoft should be sued for computer sabotage. I am losing a lot of time for cleaning my installation from the Microsoft crap.

Comment: Feel free to vent. However, this is not the place to complain to Microsoft or get changes made. See Giving Feedback on Microsoft Word or other Microsoft Product. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/giving-feedback-on-microsoft-word-or-other/8df81a9b-84aa-46ef-bf88-24fb7fec96ba